# loading bulk data for testing gives : System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded

Tags: apex, unit-test, test-setup, cpulimit

I am trying to test my batch process by loading bulk data:

I am creating the data as follows:

```
        List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
        List<Account_Plan__c> busPlans = new List<Account_Plan__c>();
        List<Opportunity> opportunities = new List<Opportunity>();

        for(Integer i = 0; i < 200 ; i++){
            Account account = createaccount();
            accounts.add(account);
            Account_Plan__c account_plan = createBusinessPlan(account, '2017','****');
            busPlans.add(account_plan);
            opportunities.add(createOpps('*****', account_plan));
        }

        insert accounts;
        insert busPlans;
        insert opportunities;
```

And this is the error message I am getting:

```
            System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded
            Class.SmartFactory.isIncludedField: line 127, column 1
            Class.SmartFactory.setFieldValue: line 150, column 1
            Class.SmartFactory.createSObject: line 71, column 1
            Class.SmartFactory.createSObject: line 78, column 1
            Class.TestObjectHelper.createAccount: line 44, column 1
            Class.TST_BatchUpdateAASPInOpportunity.createAccount: line 61, column 1
            Class.TST_BatchUpdateAASPInOpportunity.loadData: line 45, column 1
```

When does this comes? There is only 200 records which I trying to insert here.

Comment: Have you written any triggers, workflows, etc? on those objects

Comment: I am disabling all of them before starting the load data with a disable trigger call.